# Output of nettop command

Tags: networking, macos, command-line, terminal

I want to calculate net transfer of bytes(in & out) for every 2 seconds.

I'm using `nettop` to know the usage(`bytes_in` and `bytes_out`).

**Command:**

```
nettop -x -k state -k interface -k rx_dupe -k rx_ooo -k re-tx -k rtt_avg -k rcvsize -k tx_win -k tc_class -k tc_mgt -k cc_algo -k P -k C -k R -k W -l 1 -t wifi -t wired
```

Taking `bytes_in` `bytes_out` according to application summary.

**1Q).** The data(`bytes_in` and `bytes_out`) displayed is calculated from startup for every application. Am I right?

I thought I'm right and ran the `nettop` command two times with 2 seconds interval and subtracted these two values to get the net transfer of bytes for 2 seconds.

But sometimes, the first output is greater than second output.

**2Q).** How is that possible? Always the second output must be greater or equal to first output right?

**OS:** macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense if the statistics were "calculated from startup for every application" but this doesn't appear to be the case.  Confusingly, **nettop** maintains running totals since it started so you can get this data by starting a **nettop** session at the same time the application being observed is started but this is not really practical for most use cases.

It's notable that the **Network** tab in **Activity Monitor** behaves in the same way (totals are from when *it* starts, not the application being observed) since the underlying operating system service is the same for both **Activity Monitor** and **nettop**.