# Size of network packets displayed in top command

Tags: networking, macos, command-line, terminal, top

I want to calculate the network(in & out) bytes.

I used `nettop` but it's not working as expected like mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1191161/output-of-nettop-command).

So, I moved to `top`. The output shows total number of packets and total size.

What is the size of each network packet displayed in the output of `top` command?

**OS:** macOS Sierra

Comment: no version of `top` I've ever seen displays network info on that level. perhaps `iftop` would be a better fit, but you won't get per packet information from anything short of a packet analyzer like pcap or wireshark, or whatever.

Comment: Also, network packets are not a specific size, the size varies based on payload... You can't just take XXXX packets times XXXX bytes.

Comment: @FrankThomas is there a command(in-built) to know the incoming and outgoing bytes?

Answer (score 0):

B = Bytes which is 8 bits. Kib = Kilobytes. MiB = Megabytes. Gib = Gigabytes. Have you tried just using the activity monitor set to network?That works pretty well for network monitoring as well.

Comment: I want to use the code in my app. So I cant use activity monitor. And my other options are mentioned in the question.

Comment: If you use [binary prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) then it's "kibibytes", "mebibytes". Also `B` is for byte, `b` is for bit. So `Kib` is actually a kibibit. Your examples of units are a mess.